# How to update jsp status (from submitted to processing then success )if a spring batch job runing in background that will update a sql result status

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-batch

I have a jsp that initiates a long running background process. It will update status first submitted when it call the job in between it will update processing and at last it updates as success

I need to send the user some feedback during the processing time and at the same time prevent the session from timing out.

Does anyone have some details (sample code) on how this can be done?  currently the user just sits and waits with no status on the screen...which is bad.  At the end of processing there is an sql result that needs to be displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing that using the job's status from the SB tables. I think it is in the BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION  table.

Comment: i got it so you mean an ajax call needs to do that will get the data from these table. But user is not going to perform any action then how i wil do this? Next i want when the status changes in db then only that jsp field wil get updated

Comment: You schedule the ajax request with the "setInterval" function. I don't understand what JSP field are you talking about...

Comment: i mean the <div> that having status. i got It. thanks